# Placing floats from string into void array

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I get a segmentation fault when my function reads floats from a string and places them in a void array. The segfault occurs after about 200 iterations of the for loop in the following code:

```
// Allocate memory
void** data;
data = (void**)malloc(num_vals * sizeof(float));

// Convert text to floats
(*(float**)data)[0] = atof(strtok(text, " "));  
for(int index=1; index<num_vals; index++) {
    (*(float**)data)[index] = atof(strtok(NULL, " "));   
    std::cout << (*(float**)data)[index] << std::endl;
}
```

The void array is necessary because the size and type of data in the string are determined at run-time. I've tried increasing the malloc size, but it doesn't change anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: malloc returns void*, why do you cast it?

Comment: apart from the `std::cout` - this is not **c++**

Comment: Why are you using a two dimensional pointer?

Comment: what line is the seg fault at?

Comment: 1. [There is no such thing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810664/46642) as a "void array". 2. C and C++ are not the same language; you need to pick one. 3. Ugh, `strtok`.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: What are you talking about? I avoid arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Seriously??

```
std::vector<float> data;
std::istringstream str(text);
float fv;
while (str >> fv)
{
  data.push_back(fv);
}
```

Now that's c++

Comment: while this is clearly a better solution it doesn't explain the where the seg fault is or why it occurs in the op's code.

Comment: @Kevin, if the OP finds the answer unacceptable, it's his choice - I prefer to tackle the underlying problem (approach) rather than the specific issue here (which is an all too real side-effect of the approach)

Comment: I wish I could do that, but as I said, I don't know the data type of the string content or size until run-time. Still, I need to keep the data in a common structure, so I'm stuck with void pointers.

Answer (score 2):

As much as it pains me to do so, here is a version of your code that probably does what you want.

```
// Allocate memory
void* data;
data = malloc(num_vals * sizeof(float));

// Convert text to floats
((float*)data)[0] = atof(strtok(text, " "));  
for(int index=1; index<num_vals; index++) {
    ((float*)data)[index] = atof(strtok(NULL, " "));   
    std::cout << ((float*)data)[index] << '\n';
}
```

Note, however, that if you worked for me and tried to check in that code, we would have a serious discussion about your choice of career.

I'd rather see something like this:

```
std::vector<float> v;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<float>(std::istringstream(text)),
          std::istream_iterator<float>(),
          std::back_inserter(v));
```

P.s. Rob's rule #47: Never say `std::endl` when you mean `'\n'`.

Comment: I like your last few lines, but I think it's a little ambitious for the OP given the current implementation... ;)

Comment: It has to be a void** because I'm allocating the memory in a function and freeing it elsewhere. If vectors were a possibility, I would certainly use them.

Comment: @user, from your usage, you really want `void*`, not `void**`. If you have a requirement specifically for pointer-to-pointer-to-void instead of pointer-to-void, please add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you convert to `void **` ??? You code contains couple errors on indexing, so let me show some reasonable changes

```
float* data;
data = (float*)malloc(num_vals * sizeof(float));

// Convert text to floats
data[0] = atof(strtok(text, " "));  
for(int index=1; index<num_vals; index++) {
 data[index] = atof(strtok(NULL, " "));   
 std::cout << data[index] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I need to use void pointers because I don't know what the data type is until run-time, and I have to store the data in a common structure no matter what type it is.

Comment: user934904 than see answer of @Rob

Answer (score 1):

You got your types mixed up in your inexplicable attempt to create this monster under the pretence of writing "C++". Anyway. what you're mallocing is nothing but a `float*`, so you need to cast `data` back to `float*`:

```
((float*)data)[0] = myfloat;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, since you are defining a pointer of void pointer and allocating/casting it to pointer of void pointer, it allocates 4 byte memory for each element because in C/C++, regardles of the type of the pointer, pointers are always 4 bytes which are not big enough floats.

Comment: I thought floats are 4 bytes and doubles are 8 bytes.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake. It has been long time without writing in C.

Answer (score 0):

There're several issues. One is - `data` should be `void *`, you have redundant `*`. Other might be alignment, i'm not sure you are able to place a float in any location in the memory.